wrong output for partial multiplication
I tried to implement multiplication using the traditional method where you separate carries and partial and add them together. But my code doesn't give me the right output. And I am stuck on this code wondering if my concept and understanding regarding this concept are wrong.
Here I provide my code
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    int A[] = {5, 2, 3, 0, 1}; 
    int B[] = {3, 0, 8}; 
    int size_A = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    int size_B = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]); 
    int size_result = size_A + size_B + 1; 
    int* result = new int[size_result]; // Allocate memory for the array fill(result, result + size_result, 0); // Initialize result array with 0s

    for (int i = size_A - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    { 
        for (int j = size_B - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        { 
            int partial = A[i] * B[j]; 
            int position1 = i + j + 1; 
            int position2 = i + j;

            result[position1] += partial % 10;
            result[position2] += partial / 10;

            if (result[position1] >= 10) {
                result[position1 - 1] += result[position1] / 10;
                result[position1] %= 10;
            }

            if (result[position2] >= 10) {
                result[position2 - 1] += result[position2] / 10;
                result[position2] %= 10;
            }
        }
    }

    // Normalize the result to remove leading zeros 
    int startPos = 0; 
    while (result[startPos] == 0 && startPos < size_result - 1) {
        startPos++;
    }

    // Print the result 
    for (int i = startPos; i < size_result; i++) {
        cout << result[i];
    }
            
    delete[] result;// Free allocated memory
} // return 0; 

I expect someone could help me fix this code and help me to understand more about the concept of this multiplication algorithm. 
It's okay if you use Java to answer this.

In addition to showing code (✓), questions of this type should include at least one example. Each example should show input (✓), expected output (✗), and actual output (✗).

You probably want to initialise result[] first so that all its elements are zero to begin with. You can't assume that new will do this for you. There is also a marginal advantage in overheads to run the inner loop over the longer array.

What have you done to debug this? Have you tried using a debugger? For other debugging advice, see this article.

The visual-c++ tag should be removed and replaced with c++ as well. There's nothing specifically about Visual C++ here.

THere are two problems: (1) you are using new and delete instead of the normal std::vector and (2) your index calculations are incorrect, which you can plainly see by multiplying 1 by 1 and observing that the result is apparently 10. I recommend starting from the least significant digits in both the operands and the result.

I added some line breaks to make your code more readable, but I am still wondering about this comment: // Allocate memory for the array fill(result, result + size_result, 0); // Initialize result array with 0s It looks like there should be a line break in the middle, but if I add it, I am changing your code. So it's up to you to add the line break if fill(result, result + size_result, 0); is not commented out in your code.

Did you ever get your problem resolved?


I expect someone could help me fix this code and help me to understand more about the concept of this multiplication algorithm.

You should be able to use this example to modify your own method.
First I define a helper method just to convert strings to arrays.  This is so you can  visually compare results to actual BigInteger multiplications.
Function<String, int[]> toArray = n -> Arrays.stream(n.split(""))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .toArray();

Now create the arrays from some numbers and display them
String aa = "52301";
String bb = "308";
int[] a = toArray.apply(aa);
int[] b = toArray.apply(bb);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
System.out.println();

The algorithm

allocate a result array equal to the lengths of both source arrays.
nextPos is where to begin the product. Just like moving left on each subsequent line of multiplication. First time thru this starts at the end of the result array.
now use two nested loops to independently iterate across the arrays in reverse order.

first add the two array elements
then move the carry to the adjacent cell on left.
then replace the previous sum with the remainder/10 (using %)
update s to next position.


when inner loop is finished, adjust nextPos left by 1

int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];
int nextPos = 1; //start position from array length

for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int s = result.length - nextPos++;
    for (int k = b.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        result[s] += (a[i] * b[k]);  
        result[s - 1] += result[s] / 10;
        result[s] = result[s] % 10;
        s--;
    }
}

Show results as compared to BigInteger product
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
String sum = new BigInteger(aa).multiply(new BigInteger(bb)).toString();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum.split("")));

prints
[5, 2, 3, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 8]

[1, 6, 1, 0, 8, 7, 0, 8]
[1, 6, 1, 0, 8, 7, 0, 8]

The above presumes that both arrays contain digits.
